Error get_features_name_out in getting back the feature name
I want to know the feature importance to my data, so I use permutation_importance. When I get the result, it seems the feature already decoded, and I want to know the name of my feauture using get_features_name_out. It turns an error 'StandardScaler' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names_out' . If I tried to interprest manually, I am afraid there is a mistake in order. It should be (3,0,1,2) in order. Smoker, age, bmi, sex .
Here is the code
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance

# Prepare data
X = df[['age', 'bmi', 'sex', 'smoker']]
y = df['charges']

# Define the preprocessor
categorical_transformer = OneHotEncoder(drop='first', sparse=False)
numerical_transformer = StandardScaler()

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numerical_transformer, ['age', 'bmi']),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, ['sex', 'smoker'])
    ]
)

# Preprocess the data
X_preprocessed = preprocessor.fit_transform(X)

# Extract feature names
num_features = numerical_transformer.get_feature_names_out(['age', 'bmi'])
cat_features = categorical_transformer.get_feature_names_out(['sex', 'smoker'])
feature_names = np.concatenate([num_features, cat_features])

# Split the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_preprocessed, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Train KNeighborsRegressor
knn_regressor = KNeighborsRegressor()
reg_model = knn_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluate feature importance using permutation importance
results = permutation_importance(knn_regressor, X_test, y_test, n_repeats=10, random_state=42, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')

# Display feature importances with names
for i, importance in enumerate(results.importances_mean):
    print(f"Feature '{feature_names[i]}': Importance: {importance}")


sorted_indices = np.argsort(results.importances_mean)
for i in sorted_indices[::-1]:
    print(f"Feature '{feature_names[i]}', Importance: {results.importances_mean[i]}")

I want to know the names of feature back. And maybe the explanation why the order of feature importance is not correct, because I have plot manually between charges vs each feature, the correct order should be smoker, age, bmi, sex.

It does not work with the extractors because you used the preprocessor (ColumnTransformer) to fit and transform. You can get them by specifying the step within the ColumnTransformer:
preprocessor["cat"].get_feature_names_out()

